# error: cannot find symbol import android.app.ActivityTaskManager;

Tags: android, qtandroidextras

I am trying to use ActivityTaskManager in Qt for Android, but I cannot import the package as below:

```
import android.app.ActivityTaskManager;
```

Error message:

```
TestJava.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import android.app.ActivityTaskManager;
                  ^
  symbol:   class ActivityTaskManager
  location: package android.app
```

Android SDK: 29,
JDK 14

Answer (score 0):

You can't use android.app.ActivityTaskManager directly so to use this please use reflection api's